# A way to add pictures to Excel sheet programmatically but not from file

Tags: excel

I work on a product that loads a file into the Excel worksheet. The file contains data that is converted to a picture (using some WebService) and then displayed on the worksheet.

Lately, I was thinking of avoiding the file IO in this load operation. If the import file contains 1000 records then the load method has to create and delete 1000 temp files which are imported into Excel using Shapes.AddPicture() command.

Is there a way to add a picture on Excel sheet using some in-memory method and avoid the File IO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put your picture in the clipboard and paste it.

This, however, has a disadvantage of wiping off user's stuff from the clipboard which is not a good thing to do.

Comment: ya, I am sorry I forgot to mention that in the question. But I dont want to use that approach as well.